# Jquery on click action for 1 div but multiple activate

Tags: jquery

I have the following divs:

```
<div class="album">
    <div class="album-cover">
        <img src="cover.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="album-tracks">
        <ul>
            <li class="song">01 - Song</li>
            <li class="song">02 - Song</li>
            <li class="song">03 - Song</li>
            <!-- and so on -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code will be added for every album an artist has.
The jQuery that I have at the moment is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.album-tracks').hide();

    $('.album-cover').click(function() {
        if($('.album-tracks').is(':hidden')) {
            $('.album-tracks').slideDown('easeInExpo', 0);
        } else {
            $('.album-tracks').slideUp('easeOutExpo');
        }
    })
});
```

So when a user clicks on the album image the tracks will slide down. This is also the part with my problem. When a user clicks on a cover all the track lists slide down and not from that one album. Check http://jsfiddle.net/vW5s7/1/ to see the script in action.

So is there a way to only show the tracks of the clicked album and not all of the albums?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.album-tracks').hide();

    $('.album-cover').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.siblings('.album-tracks').is(':hidden')) {
            $this.siblings('.album-tracks').slideDown('easeInExpo', 0);
        } else {
            $this.siblings('.album-tracks').slideUp('easeOutExpo');
        }
    })
});
```

Working FIDDLE [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dQ28x/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `this`: http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

The Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.album-tracks').hide();

    $('.album-cover').click(function () {
        var tracks = $(this).closest('.album').find('.album-tracks');
        if (tracks.is(':hidden')) {
            tracks.slideDown('easeInExpo', 0);
        } else {
            tracks.slideUp('easeOutExpo');
        }
    })
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vW5s7/4/)